# How to Prevent Array to string conversion error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that reads a xml feed, one of the elements is country - sometime the country is blank and I get Array to string conversion error - here is my code that causes the problem if the array key country exist and there is no value in country. IS there away to prevent this error to happen.

```
   if (array_key_exists('country', $entry)) {
       $country = (string)$entry['country'];
   } else {
       $country = '';
   }
```

Comment: If you are reading from XML, the data is already a string. Why are you casting it as `(string)`? You can probably just do `$country = $entry['country'];`

Comment: what is the result of `print_r($entry['country'])` ? I don't think it contains what you believe it to contain.

Comment: It works ok most of the time, occasionally the country element in the xml is blank and that is when the error happens. The blank could be anything, I want to fool proof that when a blank, which do not often happens an error is not thrown. I have talked to the supplier of the xml, and they can not guarantee that the country is always there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the contents of `$entry['country']` is an array and not a string.  You are attempting to cast those contents to a string which is what is triggering the error.  You will need to determine what `$entry['country']` actually contains before you can determine what you want to assign to the `$country` variable.